# Trying to Decrypt a .txt file

Tags: python

So I am trying to take a .txt and run it through my program, the file has ROT13 encryption , but it wont print it out decrypted.  for an example I want it to be able to enter a file name like test.txt that has the encrypted message that then decrypts it and prints it out. This is what I have tried and need to know so improvements for it. in this code I also get a syntax error TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found. Would really like the help please.

```
    print("You selected Decrytion for Rot Cipher")
    typeofD = input("What type of Encrytion did you encrpt with, R for Rot and B for Bit Shift")
    if typeofD == 'R':
        coded = input("Enter the Test file text :")
        filecontents = open(coded,'r')
        file1 = filecontents .readlines()
        message = file1
        key = 13
        decryp_text = ""
    for i in range(len(message)):
        temp = ord(message[i]) - key
        if ord(message[i]) == 32:
            decryp_text += " "
        elif temp < 65:
            temp += 26
            decryp_text += chr(temp)
        else:
            decryp_text += chr(temp)

print("Decrypted Text: {}".format(decryp_text))
```

Comment: I think the if/elif/else block below the `for i in range(len(message))` loop was intended to be a part of the loop, but it is not.

Comment: You read in a `list` of *lines*, but process them as if it's a `list` of *characters*. Calling `ord` on a whole line is nonsensical.

Comment: Thanks John Gordon for the the information, and ShadowRanger so should I what should i change the ord with then?

Comment: You don't want to break the input into a lines.  You want the input to be one long string of text, and you examine it character by character.

Comment: You can also do `for i in message: temp = ord(i) - key` as i is the character within the string you are currently observing in the iteration, I posted a few possible solutions below.

Comment: Ahhhh I see thanks for helping! You all.

Answer (score 0):

You got things a little backwards. I've modified some of your code to work correctly. Specifically `temp = ord(message[i]) - key` was changed to `temp = ord(message[i]) + key`, `elif temp < 65` was changed to `elif temp > 122` and `temp += 26` was changed to `temp -= 26`

```
for i in range(len(message)):
    temp = ord(message[i]) + key
    if ord(message[i]) == 32:
        decryp_text += " "
    elif temp > 122:
        temp -= 26
        decryp_text += chr(temp)
    else:
        decryp_text += chr(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to perform the function in this way, or are you just attempting to do rot13? cause you could use the buildin `codec` function which has rot13 translation methods:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> inputText = "Hello World!"
>>> codecs.encode(inputText, 'rot_13')
'Uryyb Jbeyq!'
>>> outputText = codecs.encode(inputText, 'rot_13')
>>> codecs.encode(outputText, 'rot_13')
'Hello World!'
```

OR

(depending on what version of python you have) the str/string `maketrans` function which would allow you to set a 1 to 1 correlation for each character:

```
>>> rot13 = str.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklmNOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyz', 'NOPQRSTUVWXYZnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMabcdefghijklm')
>>> str.translate(inputText, rot13)
'Uryyb Jbeyq!'
>>> str.translate(outputText, rot13)
'Hello World!'
```

- Otherwise -

I would recommend doing the rotation manually as it would be easier using a type of circular array method and the modulo operation:

```
>>> alphaList
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
>>> def rot13(inputText):
...   global alphaList
...   output = []
...   for letter in inputText:
...     ascii = ord(letter)
...     if (ascii == 32):
...       output.append(' ')
...     else:
...       transLetter = alphaList[(alphaList.index(letter.upper()) + 13 ) % 26]
...     if (ascii >= 97 and ascii <= 122):
...       transLetter = transLetter.lower()
...     output.append(transLetter)
...   output = ''.join(output)
...   return(output)

>>> msg = rot13('Hello World')
>>> msg
'Uryyb bJbeyq'
```

This last one I didn't take into account special characters or anything, but the logic should be apparent now. Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it help me figure it out!